# Dynamic height() with window resize() with variable margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize

So if have this function in order to dynamically set a div's height based on the browser height:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#slideshow').height($(window).height() - 110);
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

This works like a charm. As you can see, there's a 110px margin (that belongs to my header height).

This code is not optimal since, a header height might vary based on the current viewport.

Is there a way to set this up dynamically as well? Or at least set some conditions like:

If browser width is more than 768px then set a 110px margin. If less than 767, then the margin should be 80px.

This is my edited code so far, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right path:

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    var set_width = $(window).width();
    if(set_width <= 767) 

    $('#slideshow').height($(window).height() - 110);
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

---

Now that I think of it better, this 110px are not a margin, it's a subtraction I'm doing in order for my header and the slideshow to fill the entire window. If I don't do this subtraction then I end up with my header height + slideshow height (which takes take browser height) making it scroll.

So I don't think I can do this with CSS. That's why I was thinking on a Javascript solution.

Comment: While it's all nice and good to implement this in JavaScript have you considered implementing the responsiveness in CSS using media queries?

Comment: @Halcyon How can I implement this in CSS if the height is dynamic?

Comment: @Johann, media queries won't help you set dynamic height, do calculations etc.

Comment: @LShetty That's what I thought. Could you take me in right direction please?

Comment: Does this work for you - [http://jsfiddle.net/L1j4kkav/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/L1j4kkav/1/)?

Comment: @LShetty Wow! Works like a charm. Post it as answer so I can mark it :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/53hoq9w7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you'd need something like the following. I hope the code is straightforward.

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {

    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var headerHeight = $("header").height();
    $('#slideshow').height(winHeight - headerHeight);
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

The sample HTML I'd used as a model is:

```
<body>
    <header>my header</header>
    <div id="slideshow"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var buffer = ($(window).width()<768)?80:110;
    $('#slideshow').height($(window).height() - buffer );
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

As Halcyon suggested in comments, use css. That is the neatest way to do it.

Comment: I think your solution is more on the right path, please check updated question.  Is the: var buffer = ($(window).height()<768)?80:110; part correct? I thought it would be:     var buffer = ($(window).width()<768)?80:110; instead